# .conf page for Firefox's about:config

Tags: firefox, configuration

Is there any such `.conf` file for Firefox to edit `about:config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rinzwind already pointed out, the `prefs.js` file is what changes when you use `about:config`.  It actually is a javascript file though, but it mostly just calls the `user_pref()` function many times (for me it’s over 100).

If you’re looking to make changes to Firefox configuration though it generally works better to create a `user.js` file in the same location as `prefs.js`.  On startup, Firefox first runs `prefs.js` to load those settings, then runs `user.js`.  Once you exit, the settings from `user.js` are also saved in `prefs.js`.  Firefox doesn’t write to `user.js` so you won’t lose your settings, and it’ll be easy to manage just a few lines of settings there instead of being mixed in with everything else in `prefs.js`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an `about:config` string in `prefs.js` or `user.js`? And is there any variable I can use in this files? I want to use a variable in a string that represents the Firefox version in use.

Comment: I haven’t tried using variables, but here’s an example line I have in my `user.js` from back when I tried out spell check in single-line input fields (includes a comment at the end, which is optional):

`user_pref("layout.spellcheckDefault", 1);  // set to 2 to spellcheck in single-line inputs, 1 for normal`

Comment: What was the `about:config` line? I want to know which part goes where.

Comment: `layout.spellcheckDefault` shows in the Preference Name column, and `1` shows in the Value column.  Since 1 is actually the default here, the Status shows default and not user set.  The Type column is to help you know what sort of values you can set.  For example a string value would need the value in quotes.  If you’re not sure what to put in user.js you can make the change in `about:config` and then search for the Preference Name in prefs.js after exiting Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look iin your `~/.mozilla/` directory for a `prefs.js`. It is a plain text file (and not javascript). More info about pref.js [on the mozilla site](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file)